# AWS CloudFormation not creating initial instance in Auto Scaling group

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation

(Expired Pastbin Link Removed)

Then I try to create a stack is fails to create the Auto Scaling group as no EC2 instances are created. How do I trigger the creation of the initial instance?

```
Received 0 SUCCESS signal(s) out of 1. Unable to satisfy 100% MinSuccessfulInstancesPercent requirement
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I believe I was able to replicate your symptoms with your template - the issue may be related to the AMI you're using.  I selected the AMI for my region from the marketplace link as referenced by the shortened url in the parameter description.  I'm still waiting for resource creation to fail (been almost an hour!) but otherwise the symptoms match up.

While launching, the scaling group is visible in the ASG console but with 0 instances.  However, the Activity History tab shows a number of attempts to launch an instance, and all fail:

[image: ASG console screenshot]

The description on all of them is:

> Description: Launching a new EC2 instance. Status Reason: In
>   order to use this AWS Marketplace product you need to accept terms and
>   subscribe. To do so please visit
>   http://aws.amazon.com/marketplace/pp?sku=aw0evgkw8e5c1q413zgy5pjce.
>   Launching EC2 instance failed.

Have you accepted the terms and subscribed to that AMI in the marketplace?  There are more details here: https://aws.amazon.com/marketplace/help/200799470#topic1

Note: I believe you will only see the ASG in the console while cloudformation is waiting for it - after the cfn rolls back, the asg (and the activity history) will disappear. As I'm still waiting for the asg resource creation to fail, I haven't definitely confirmed this.

Comment: Sorry, I'm not sure I did replicate what you were seeing - after failure (took an hour!) the status reason on the ASG CREATE_FAILED event is " Group did not stabilize. {current/minSize/maxSize} group size = {0/2/3}. Failed Scaling Activity: In order to use this AWS Marketplace product you need to accept terms and subscribe. To do so please visit http://aws.amazon.com/marketplace/pp?sku=aw0evgkw8e5c1q413zgy5pjce. Launching EC2 instance failed.", not the "Received 0 SUCCESS signal(s) out of 1" error that you saw...  If accepting the terms didn't resolve your issue, feel free to unaccept!

Comment: Hello Chris. I'm having the same error message "Group did not stabilize". Did you fix this? I opened a case with AWS support.

Comment: I believe what this error means is that the EC2 instances in the ASG are not able to initialise - the ASG retries a number of times but eventually fails with the "Group did not stabilize" error.  The reasons why an EC2 instance may not initialise are many - error in the UserData script, or a terms and conditions requirement in the AWS Marketplace (as above), or  an expired or no longer available AMI... Review the Activity History in the ASG (while it's attempting to create) and you should see at least one 'failed' record - expand that for more info on your instances.

Comment: Hey @Chris Actually the error is not very detailed. I really needed to go down to the instance logs. I found some issues where my User Data Script, some RPMs were not installed successfully. I think when that error happens means that you really need to go down to the bone inside the EC2 instance itself.

Comment: Going to add a "me too" comment, as well as to say that while my root cause was not the same, the "power move" here was to look at the activity log of the auto scaling group before CloudFormation rolls back your stack.

In my case, I was using the wrong architecture for my AMI, and the logged error was very explicit.

Answer (score 2):

Verify that the subnets where AutoScalingGroup's instances will be installed can connect to Internet using either a NAT gateway or Internet gateway.  This because the instances install some packages from Internet in the UserData statement of the stack.

Answer (score 1):

I had this issue, using other answers was able to detect it was possibly linked to the user data scripts.
I removed -xe from  #!/bin/bash -xe
As it was causing the script to exit before this line was complete
/opt/aws/bin/cfn-signal -e $? --stack ${AWS::StackName} --resource ECSAutoScalingGroup --region ${AWS::Region}

Answer (score 0):

Note - please see the other answer for the more likely culprit.  Leaving this here as the missing configset may also cause problems once the first issue is resolved.

The UserData calls cfn-init which references a configset `InstallAndRun` that doesn't exist:

```
                    "/opt/aws/bin/cfn-init ",
                    "         --stack ", { "Ref" : "AWS::StackName" },
                    "         --resource LaunchConfig",
                    "         --configsets InstallAndRun ",
                    "         --region ", { "Ref" : "AWS::Region" },"\n",
```

To use cfn-init and specify a configset, you need to have specified a `AWS::CloudFormation::Init` block in the launch configuration metadata and include a configset definition referencing the config elements you wish cfn-init to execute.  See http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-resource-init.html#aws-resource-init-configsets for more details.

As an example, you'd need:

```
"LaunchConfig" : {
  "Type" : "AWS::AutoScaling::LaunchConfiguration"    
  "Metadata" : {
    "AWS::CloudFormation::Init" : {
      "configSets" : {
        "InstallAndRun" : [ "config1" ]
      },
      "config1" : {
        "commands" : {
          "test" : {
            "command" : "echo \"$MAGIC\" > test.txt",
            "env" : { "MAGIC" : "I come from the environment!" },
            "cwd" : "~",
            "test" : "test ! -e ~/test.txt",
            "ignoreErrors" : "false"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "Properties" : {
     ...
  }
}
```

Without that Metadata, cfn-init will fail, and the cfn-signal line tell cloudformation that the resource initialisation has failed.

As a diagnostic process, try removing the reference to cfn-init and cfn-signal and seeing if the instance starts up.  If it does, and you do have some instance configuration steps that you'd like to define using cfn-init, define the metadata block to specify the steps, and add the calls to cfn-init and cfn-signal back into the user data.

Comment: Hey chris. No EC2 instances launch at all, so I'm not sure how its an issue with user data?

Comment: Do you mean you see no EC2 instances in the EC2 console screen?  That is odd - but the thing that prompted me to look at cfn-signal was the message `Received 0 SUCCESS signal(s) out of 1.` - that suggests that  it received a signal but none of them indicated success.  For it to have received a signal, I can only guess that the userdata script has executed...  World it be worth testing with some modified userdata?  Another option would be to try removing the cfn-signal line or replacing `-e $?` with `-e 0` which should signal success no matter what happens with cfn-init.

Comment: I only added the cnf-init after trying to troubleshoot why nothing was happening. You should be able to replicate by running my template. After a long timeout it fails with Received 0 succhess signal(s) out of 1. I believed the 1 was due to timeout.

Comment: OK - I believe I've replicated it - as the answer is completely different, have added a 2nd answer.

Answer (score 0):

I am sure someone might find this answer helpful. I had similar issue when I created Auto Scaling Group, I tried to debug the logs(cfn-init) where I could find nothing wrong. I had removed Creation Policy and Update Policy in the Auto Scaling Group as mentioned here https://serverfault.com/questions/1023697/received-0-success-signals-out-of-1-unable-to-satisfy-100-minsuccessfulinsta.
Everything else like LB, Launch Config, Subnets, SGs were all creating successfully, however I was stuck on this particular issue for a while.

Comment: Update: I was referring to wrong resource(launchConfig) in the userData, that was causing the timeout. Once I changed it from launchConfig to AutoScalingGroup, the error got resolved.

Answer (score 0):

If you used CreatePolicy , the cloudformation service expect and notification back ( like one from cfn-init) to confirm the success . If not it will continue to throw error "Received 0 SUCCESS signal(s) out of 2. Unable to satisfy 100% MinSuccessfulInstancesPercent requirement"

Best way to solve is to have cfn-init to report back success to cloudformation. If you donot use cfn-init and follow boot script in Userdata section, best way is to avoid CreatePolicy all together.