# CloudFormation Template Issue when launching WordPress

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation

I am trying to use CloudFormation for a WordPress site. I am using the template provided by AWS and 3/4 of the way I am having error which is terminating the process:

```
12:39:17 UTC-0400   ROLLBACK_IN_PROGRESS    AWS::CloudFormation::Stack  MyProdWPSite    The following resource(s) failed to create: [WebServerGroup]. . Rollback requested by user.
Physical ID:arn:aws:cloudformation:us-west-2:085664598559:stack/MyProdWPSite/955a5660-6b0a-11e7-a813-503aca41a061
Client Request Token:Console-CreateStack-6768960d-41f1-4d9b-b641-b8220af0e895

12:39:16 UTC-0400   CREATE_FAILED   AWS::AutoScaling::AutoScalingGroup  WebServerGroup  Received 0 SUCCESS signal(s) out of 1. Unable to satisfy 100% MinSuccessfulInstancesPercent requirement
Physical ID:MyProdWPSite-WebServerGroup-1DXD0NN8C0R00
Client Request Token:Console-CreateStack-6768960d-41f1-4d9b-b641-b8220af0e895
```

How can I solve this issue?

Comment: Check this link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39014624/aws-cloudformation-not-creating-initial-instance-in-auto-scaling-group

Comment: Can you please share the URL of that template?

Comment: Seems like your health checks are failing, this could be due to many reasons including VPC security group limitations, private subnets & etc.

Comment: Did you use the template from the [CloudFormation Sample Solutions](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/sample-templates-applications-us-west-1.html) page?